# Storing data before passing it to interpolation routine

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'll begin by apologizing, because I'm entirely new to python(Fortran guy here), and have been learning on the fly. As a result, there are probably some pretty glaring holes in my knowledge that may be obvious after reading my current dilemma.

I have some data that will need to be written to a file, where it can then be read by an interpolation algorithm. At the moment, that interpolation algorithm will probably the RectBivariateSpline from SciPi. While the intervals of X and Y aren't the same, they are regular, so that would seem to be ideal.

The data is generally of the form

X1,Y1,F(X1,Y1)

X1,Y2,F(X1,Y2)

X1,Y3,F(X1,Y3)

X2,Y1,F(X2,Y1)

X2,Y2,F(X2,Y2)

X2,Y3,F(X2,Y3)

etc...

In this case F(X,Y) isn't an explicit mathematical function, but rather a data point for a physical quantity at X,Y.

The data is being read in from a data source I basically can't control, using

```
 data_array = np.loadtxt(Path/DataFile, dtype = Float, delimiter = ";", usecols = #)
```

In this case there are conceivably a few different columns with different data, but they all depend on X and Y. There is a separate file that contains the information regarding the range and stepsize of the X and Y quantities that I read in and stored in an array. At least, I'm fairly certain it is an array rather than a list, since I read somewhere that np.loadtxt and np.genfromtxt both generate numpy arrays rather than vanilla python lists.

I've toyed with a variety of ideas for how to optimally store this data to be transferred to another machine using a simple interpolation routine, but I could use some advice. It first occurred to me to use

```
ArrayExample = np.Empty(xRange,yRange) 
For n in (xRange) 
    For m in (yRange) 
        ArrayExample[n,m] = F(X,Y)
```

However this does nothing to preserve the actual quantity X or Y associated with the value in the array, and those are necessary for interpolation, and it is definitely necessary for plotting.

So then it occurred to me that since I've got the values of X and Y in a form I can pretty readily read from, I could do something as follows. Where xvalues and yvalues are the arrays holding the actual X and Y values.

```
ArrayExample = np.Empty(xRange,yRange,1) 
For n in (xRange) 
    For m in (yRange) 
        ArrayExample[n,m,1] = (xvalues[n],yvalues[m],F(X,Y))
```

After which it occurs to me to save ArrayExample as a pickle file to be moved wherever, and then brought in using pickle on the other end.

However, once I have it there, I really don't know how to get RectBivariateSpline to take the data. I've tried reading the documentation on the scipy site and googling, but everything I've found thus far has pretty unhelpful. If anyone has any good examples of how to use it hanging around, it would be very helpful.

Any advice, thoughts, or criticisms you may have would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this earlier and hoped somebody who knew more than I do replied.
Hopefully this can point you in the right direction

To use the RectBivariateSpline class you need x and y as 1d arrays with the z values as a 2d array(len(x), len(y))

Numpy needs any specific array indices to be integers, not floats.  The x and y coordinates need to be converted to integer indices to place the z data into an array.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

# Generate x and y arrays
x = np.linspace(45., 70., 70)
y = np.linspace(125/7, 59.876, 29)

# I don't know what your data looks like. Generate a list of dictionary records
data = []

for _x in x:
    for _y in y:
        data.append({'x': _x, 'y': _y, 'z': _x * _x - _y*_y/_x})

data[:100:10]
Out[4]: 
[{'x': 45.0, 'y': 17.857142857142858, 'z': 2017.9138321995465},
 {'x': 45.0, 'y': 32.86387755102041, 'z': 2000.9992344958118},
 {'x': 45.0, 'y': 47.870612244897956, 'z': 1974.075655184414},
 {'x': 45.36231884057971, 'y': 19.357816326530614, 'z': 2049.4792585649284},
 {'x': 45.36231884057971, 'y': 34.364551020408165, 'z': 2031.7068577153198},
 {'x': 45.36231884057971, 'y': 49.37128571428571, 'z': 2004.0054192006007},
 {'x': 45.72463768115942, 'y': 20.858489795918366, 'z': 2081.227345221296},
 {'x': 45.72463768115942, 'y': 35.86522448979592, 'z': 2062.610735570439},
 {'x': 45.72463768115942, 'y': 50.87195918367347, 'z': 2034.1437652565721},
 {'x': 46.08695652173913, 'y': 22.359163265306123, 'z': 2113.159976357177}]

def indexer(v):
    """ Returns a function to index into the array v by value.
        int( result + 0.5 ) to avoid any not quite equal with floats.
    """
    v_lo = v.min()
    v_range = v.max()-v_lo
    n = len(v)-1

    def func( x ):
        """ Returns an index from x. """
        return int(n*(x-v_lo)/v_range+0.5)
    return func

x_index = indexer(x)  # Function to index into the x values 
y_index = indexer(y)  # Function to index into the y values

z = np.empty((len(x), len(y)))

for rec in data:
    ix_x = x_index(rec['x'])  # Map the x value to an index
    ix_y = y_index(rec['y'])  # Map the y value to an index
    z[ix_x, ix_y] = rec['z']  # Place the z value at ix_x, ix_y

inter = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline( x, y, z)

inter(45.3, 18)  # Out[6]: array([[2044.93768211]])

inter(np.arange(45., 70.), 18)
Out[7]: 
   array([[2017.8       ], [2108.95652174], [2202.10638298], [2297.25      ],
          [2394.3877551 ], [2493.52      ], [2594.64705882], [2697.76923077],
          [2802.88679245], [2910.        ], [3019.10909091], [3130.21428571],
          [3243.31578947], [3358.4137931 ], [3475.50847458], [3594.6       ],
          [3715.68852459], [3838.77419355], [3963.85714286], [4090.9375    ],
          [4220.01538462], [4351.09090909], [4484.1641791 ], [4619.23529412],
          [4756.30434783]])
```

Hopefully some pointers/ideas at least.

Comment: Your comment actually did offer me a bit of insight, enough for me to get it working as desired. I'll post the entire code in a few hours, in case anyone might find it useful.